# Android Crash When Connecting to SQL Server

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jtds

I am having an issue with an app I am testing. I am using Android Studio and JTDS 1.3.1. I am just trying to test connecting to the database. The end product will be a label application only used within our company on our network. I have tried Microsoft's JDBC driver as well, with no success. The app crashes when it tries to create a connection. I have added JTDS as a module and a dependency. The app is just a button that calls a static method and a text view to display an error or success if it works. If I don't load the database driver I do get a `SqlException` error for no suitable driver found. When I do load the driver the app closes with no error reported.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBHelper {

    public static String checkConnection() {
        String message;
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server-name/database-name";


        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, username, password)) {
            message = "Success";
            return message;
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            message = sqle.getMessage();
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late but try using jtds 1.2.7 version jar

Comment: why a downgraded jTDS version will work? Please write reasons or point to the link if you know the issue.

Comment: I honestly don't know, but I got stuck in this issue for hours.. downgrading to 1.2.7 worked just fine